# Why httpGet action method not display the data into view in mvc 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

My problem is view model,when I pass values http get action to to http post action through view, view method not display the values it is directly showing http post action without display the view method Why it is not displaying view?

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return view();
}
```

View model

```
public class sample
{
  [Key]
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Name{ get; set; } 
}
```

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Name);
  <input type="Submit" Value="Index"/>
}
```

Post method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string name)
{
  return view();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it does _not display the values_? What values? Your POST method only returns the current view. And you not even binding to your model. What do you expect?

Comment: what is your model, show model class

Comment: public class sample
        {
            [Key]
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Name{ get; set; }

Comment: Change your post method to `public ActionResult Index(sample model) { return view(model); }` so the values are bound and returned.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not using the `HttPPost` method correctly. You should be doing it this way:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(sample model)
{
  return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

pass appropriate model class object with values while returning view in HTTPGet method and
 in your view bind the same model as @model modelname